# EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/node_modules/node-sass/build' while running npm install on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli, package.json, node-sass

i have an angular 4 app and i want to run it on ubuntu. i copied all project files , package.json and package-lock.json to a folder in winscp but i didn't copy node_modules! now when i run npm install, i get the errors like this:

```
> node-sass@4.7.2 install /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.9.1 install /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Unable to save binary /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:885:18)
    at sync (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at Function.sync (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at checkAndDownloadBinary (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:114:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:157:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.9.4 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.12\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.9.4
gyp verb command install [ '8.9.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.9.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.9.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.9.4
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-124-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1

> node-sass@4.9.1 postinstall /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
gyp info using node@8.9.4 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.12\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 8.9.4
gyp verb command install [ '8.9.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.9.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.9.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 8.9.4
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-124-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/cms/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-07-07T10_49_32_298Z-debug.log
```

i did the steps that i said before to run my project, but i don't know whats going on here now? 
i also did rm -rf node_modules, rm package-lock.json, npm cache clean --force and used npm install again but it's still not working!

Comment: Have you tried to run these commands with `sudo`?

Comment: @R.Richards yes I did! but still the same error

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I get the exact same error running ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 21):

Add --unsafe-perm flag while installing

*For linux/mac*

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

**For windows environment , hit same command removing sudo**

Comment: No need for `sudo` and the global flag `-g`. This is fine -> `npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass`

Answer (score 1):

On Linux/mac

```
npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Just adding unsafe-perm would work. Using sudo would give unnecessary permissions to `node modules` and mess things with the file system.

Comment: Thanks to @A1rPun for suggesting this approach.

Comment: Thanks! this was much needed inside a redhat node docker container to make our CI/CD pipeline work.